# Encoding error when attempt to install matplotlib on ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, matplotlib

I'm attempting to install matplotlib in a python2 virtualenv in Ubuntu 14.04, and am running into the following error:

```
../virtualenv/bin/pip install matplotlib


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/sites/dashboard.mysite.com/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 211, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/me/sites/dashboard.mysite.com/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 305, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/home/me/sites/dashboard.mysite.com/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 705, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/home/me/sites/dashboard.mysite.com/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 334, in prepare_files
    functools.partial(self._prepare_file, finder))
  File "/home/me/sites/dashboard.mysite.com/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 321, in _walk_req_to_install
    more_reqs = handler(req_to_install)
  File "/home/me/sites/dashboard.mysite.com/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 491, in _prepare_file
    session=self.session)
  File "/home/me/sites/dashboard.mysite.com/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 825, in unpack_url
    session,
  File "/home/me/sites/dashboard.mysite.com/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 673, in unpack_http_url
    from_path, content_type = _download_http_url(link, session, temp_dir)
  File "/home/me/sites/dashboard.mysite.com/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 886, in _download_http_url
    _download_url(resp, link, content_file)
  File "/home/me/sites/dashboard.mysite.com/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 621, in _download_url
    for chunk in progress_indicator(resp_read(4096), 4096):
  File "/home/me/sites/dashboard.mysite.com/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/ui.py", line 133, in iter
    for x in it:
  File "/home/me/sites/dashboard.mysite.com/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 586, in resp_read
    decode_content=False):
  File "/home/me/sites/dashboard.mysite.com/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/response.py", line 307, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
  File "/home/me/sites/dashboard.mysite.com/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/response.py", line 243, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt)
  File "/home/me/sites/dashboard.mysite.com/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/filewrapper.py", line 54, in read
    self.__callback(self.__buf.getvalue())
  File "/home/me/sites/dashboard.mysite.com/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/controller.py", line 224, in cache_response
    self.serializer.dumps(request, response, body=body),
  File "/home/me/sites/dashboard.mysite.com/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/serialize.py", line 49, in dumps
    "body": _b64_encode_bytes(body),
  File "/home/me/sites/dashboard.mysite.com/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/serialize.py", line 12, in _b64_encode_bytes
    return base64.b64encode(b).decode("ascii")
MemoryError
```

Any thoughts about what might be going on and why I am getting a Memory Error?

Comment: The traceback is incomplete. Please paste the full output.

Comment: That's all of the traceback that I got. The only other output is the beginning `Collecting matplotlib
  Downloading matplotlib-1.4.3.tar.gz (50.4MB)
    99% |████████████████████████████████| 50.4MB 18.5MB/s eta 0:00:01Exception:` . Perhaps there is a more verbose option?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be the MemoryError while trying to install a large package (matplotlib) in a low memory environment. It appears that the cause is the caching mechanism, as disabling the cache fixes the issue.

Try this:

`pip install --no-cache-dir matplotlib`